# How can I create an expression regular in .htaccess matching with 2 values or empty?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to create an expression regular that matches with only 2 values or empty. It'd be something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(en|pt|{regex_empty_here})$ /index.html [L,QSA]
```

It means it can only accept 3 options (and nothing else): `/pt`, `/en` or `/`. All them should display the `index.html` as I wrote above.

How I could achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^(en|pt|{regex_empty_here})$ /index.html [L,QSA]
> ```

You can literally have an *empty* alternation subpattern:

```
RewriteRule ^(en|pt|)$ /index.html [L,QSA]
```

HOWEVER, the rule won't be successful because of the preceding condition that checks that the request does not map to a directory! A request for `/` is a directory.

But neither does it need to work for the root directory, since mod_dir should issue an internal subrequest for the directory index - providing it is configured to do so. For example:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
```

(Although this is the Apache default, so you wouldn't necessarily need to explicitly set this.)